# Custom Actions for Visual Studio Database Project

Tags: database, visual-studio, custom-action

I have an XSD (schema) file that I use to create SQL files.  I'd like to create a custom tool so that I can place it all into a Visual Studio 2015 project.  Has anyone here found a way to add a Custom Tool action to a Visual Studio Database project?